# Type 1 surge protection: parallel or series?

Tags: power, mains, theory, surge-protection

Type 1 surge protection devices (SPDs) are installed at the outside edge of electric service, usually between the power meter and the meter base/socket, and protect the entire house.  But how do they work electrically?

SPD types 2 and 3 work entirely in parallel with the protected devices; when there is a surge, the SPD basically loads the circuit to draw the voltage back down.  Do Type 1 SPDs work this same way, or is there also a series aspect to their operation?

I seem to remember reading that a Type 1 SPD can create some isolation between the house and power line.  In other words, it would absorb the surge voltage between (in series with) the line and the house.  Is this the case?

Comment: SPD use in meter cans is not that common any more. Recent UL and ISO standards require so much fusing and breakers that they have moved inside into SPD rated steel or plastic enclosures. They go by protection modes, phase to phase, phase to neutral, phase to GND, neutral to GND. Meter cans have almost no room for multiple MOV's.

Comment: The entire manufacturing plant/house/apartment/trailer is protected. Manufacturing plants may have an SPD at each sub-panel and large horse-power motors.

Comment: My meter is inside my house so how does that work? Pretty much the same for everyone in the UK.

Comment: Good question!  I will clarify.